# What is the most resource efficient way to test if two std::lists contain the same unique elements?

Tags: c++, list, c++17, comparison, std

In my code, I have to compare keys from structures that are returned in a random order as a list. I need to check if the two structures have the same key elements, ignoring the order and only comparing unique elements.

At the moment, I use code like the one shown in the next example:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <string>


template<typename T>
auto areListsAsSetsEqual(const std::list<T> &a, const std::list<T> &b) -> bool {
    auto aSet = std::set<T>{a.begin(), a.end()};
    auto bSet = std::set<T>{b.begin(), b.end()};
    return aSet == bSet;
}


auto main() -> int {
    auto x = std::list<std::string>{"red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "green"};
    auto y = std::list<std::string>{"blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "red"};
    auto z = std::list<std::string>{"green", "red", "yellow"};

    auto xyEqual = areListsAsSetsEqual(x, y);
    assert(xyEqual == true);
    auto xzEqual = areListsAsSetsEqual(x, z);
    assert(xzEqual == false);
    return 0;
}
```

It works and is short and reliable code, but for every comparison, two new sets must be created, and all elements from the two lists must be copied.

**Is there a more efficient and elegant way to compare the two lists for the same unique elements, using less CPU and/or memory?**

Comment: I suppose that you can use `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::set` but I don't see a very better way.

Comment: `std::list` itself is usually not considered efficient.

Comment: @max66 Nevertheless, a good hint. Creating an unordered set may be faster. The question is if the slower comparison counterbalances the gain.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed, but that is what I get and have to work with.

Comment: In the case the size of the sets is different, the comparison is constant time in both cases. So the unordered set comparison can be worst when the sets are equal or very similar (when the keys are really different, I suppose the comparison terminate almost immediately in both cases) so I suppose the slower comparison can be a problem only when the sets are ever equal or similar.

Comment: you can avoid creating new containers by sorting the initial ones, not sure if that is actually better in terms of complexity. `std::list` is rather poor in terms of performance to begin with

Comment: My thinking is more of a space optimization. But one list can "turn on" a key in something like an unordered_map. The other list can then "turn off" keys IFF they are found, else early return. Finally, scan the unordered_map for any keys still left "on."

Comment: The answer should have a big "it depends": Can you increase space complexity by using additional containers? Can you change the input? As already mentioned sorting the list then traversing them could be a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different take. It only requires one new container, and only one list is copied.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename T>
auto areListsAsSetsEqual(const std::list<T>& a, const std::list<T>& b) -> bool {
  std::unordered_map<T, bool> firstListKeys;
  for (const auto& i : a) {
    firstListKeys[i] = true;
  }

  for (const auto& i : b) {
    if (firstListKeys.find(i) != firstListKeys.end()) {
      firstListKeys[i] = false;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (const auto& p : firstListKeys) {
    if (p.second == true) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

auto main() -> int {
  auto x = std::list<std::string>{"red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "green"};
  auto y = std::list<std::string>{"blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "red"};
  auto z = std::list<std::string>{"green", "red", "yellow"};

  auto xyEqual = areListsAsSetsEqual(x, y);
  assert(xyEqual == true);
  auto xzEqual = areListsAsSetsEqual(x, z);
  assert(xzEqual == false);
  return 0;
}
```

The first list is copied in to the `std::unordered_map` and each key is set to `true`. The second list is iterated and searches the map (O(1)). If not found, we can immediately return. If found, the key is set to `false`. We then have to search the `unordered_map` to see if any elements were left in the `true` state.

I haven't run any benchmarks, so testing would be required to see if this solution is any more efficient. On paper, both run at O(3N), but average run-time would need to be tested.

But while runtime efficiency gains are nebulous, this method does offer a clear space efficiency advantage. Your current algorithm currently requires ~2N space, where mine is closer to N.

Comment: I suggest adding `std::unordered_map<T, unsigned int>` instead of `std::unordered_map<T, bool>` and use the value as a counter. Otherwise, you can't account for repeated elements. Still need three passes, list `a` increases the counter, then traversing list `b` decreases the counter, and finally check that all values in the map are `0`, otherwise both lists are not equal.

Comment: @JorgeLópez That isn't the question being asked. OP only cares about the same *unique* values existing in both lists. Look at their example code again, specifically the `main()` function. And to hammer the point home [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) can only hold unique values.

Comment: ops, you are right and I made a boo boo.

Comment: Indeed, I suggest you update your answer to actually reflect the intent of the original question. I also suggest using an unordered set.

Comment: Your first suggestion is unnecessary. I am answering the question directly, there's nothing to clarify in that regard. The "original" question just had one extra tag compared to what's seen now. Your misunderstanding was not the fault of OP or me. Citing the "original question" is interesting wording in this case. As to your second suggestion; I considered it. I stuck with the unordered_map for subjective reasons, but after reading a bit on unordered_set removal being an (on average) O(1) operation, I may edit an alternate version. It can reduce the run-time to O(2N).

Comment: This seems like an interesting approach. I will have to test this.

Comment: Of the two answers, yours is the most efficient so far. It only uses approximately 53% of the CPU resources and it is more memory efficient than the original method.

Comment: A quick update: I won't be editing in a solution using a `std::unordered_set`. Approximate runtime is equivalent because you have run `std::unique` on the second list, and it's a bit more complicated overall.

Comment: @sweenish See my answer for a solution based on your principle, but without requiring copying the keys. For my use case, I got a speedup of almost ten times to my original method. Yet, with large sets of short keys, your solution is superior.

Comment: I wonder if I could shave some time by specializing the function for strings to make the key a `string_view` instead. Not enough make enough of an impact compared to your algorithm, though.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake: you can also try to go with std algorithms. Assuming you don't want to modify your inputs, you'll need copies. (For a solution with only one copy, see @sweenish answer.)

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto areListsEqual(std::list<T> const &a, std::list<T> const &b) -> bool {
    std::vector<T> aVector(a.size());
    std::partial_sort_copy(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), aVector.begin(), aVector.end());
    auto aEnd = std::unique(aVector.begin(), aVector.end());
    
    std::vector<T> bVector(b.size());
    std::partial_sort_copy(b.cbegin(), b.cend(), bVector.begin(), bVector.end());
    auto bEnd = std::unique(bVector.begin(), bVector.end());

    return std::distance(aVector.begin(),aEnd) == std::distance(bVector.begin(),bEnd)
         ? std::equal(aVector.begin(), aEnd, bVector.begin())
         : false;
}

auto main() -> int {
    auto x = std::list<std::string>{"red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "green"};
    auto y = std::list<std::string>{"blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "red"};
    auto z = std::list<std::string>{"green", "red", "yellow"};
    auto w = std::list<std::string>{"green", "red", "yellow", "black"};

    auto xyEqual = areListsEqual(x, y);
    assert(xyEqual == true);
    auto xzEqual = areListsEqual(x, z);
    assert(xzEqual == false);
    auto xwEqual = areListsEqual(x, w);
    assert(xwEqual == false);
    return 0;
}
```

This solution would not be faster in terms of "big-O". But it uses sequential containers as intermediate storage, which might be more cache-efficient on modern hardware. As always with optimisations nowadays, you have to measure with representative data.

Comment: You have a good point there. I will have to test this.

Comment: Compared with the original method, yours requires only approximately 76% if the CPU resources.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness of this question, the fastest algorithm is roughly based on the answer from [sweenish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6119582/sweenish) but works **without copies** of the original data. Therefore the following algorithm is superior under the following two conditions:

- Creating a copy/hash of the elements in the list is expensive (e.g. for `std::string` or strings in general.
- Searching for elements sequentially in the container is fast (short lists, fast compare).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
auto areListsAsSetsEqual(const std::list<T> &a, const std::list<T> &b) -> bool {
    auto keyMap = std::vector<bool>(a.size(), false);
    const auto srcEndA = a.end();
    const auto srcEndB = b.end();
    std::size_t keyIndex = 0;
    for (auto it = a.begin(); it != srcEndA; ++it, ++keyIndex) {
        if (std::find(a.begin(), it, *it) == it) {
            keyMap[keyIndex] = true;
        }
    }
    for (const auto &element : b) {
        auto foundIt = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), element);
        if (foundIt == a.end()) {
            return false;
        }
        keyMap[std::distance(a.begin(), foundIt)] = false;
    }
    return std::all_of(keyMap.begin(), keyMap.end(), [](bool flag) -> bool { return !flag; });
}

auto main() -> int {
    auto x = std::list<std::string>{"red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "green"};
    auto y = std::list<std::string>{"blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "red"};
    auto z = std::list<std::string>{"green", "red", "yellow"};

    auto xyEqual = areListsAsSetsEqual(x, y);
    assert(xyEqual == true);
    auto xzEqual = areListsAsSetsEqual(x, z);
    assert(xzEqual == false);
    return 0;
}
```

Using my extensive test data that uses `std::string` keys with sizes from 4 up to 128 characters and key sets of zero to 32 elements. Making 200'000 comparisons of sets with small mutations, I get these results:

| Implementation | Avg Time per Call | Avg Time if Equal | Speed Gain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| original | 0.005232 ms | 0.005444 ms | 1× |
| kaba | 0.004337 ms | 0.004275 ms | 1.21× |
| sweenish | 0.002796 ms | 0.003919 ms | 1.87× |
| this solution | 0.000566 ms | 0.001305 ms | 9.24× |

The algorithm also has the lowest memory usage.